# fetch post form with ref values

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms, express

I am trying to send data with this form :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ToDoForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
       event.preventDefault();

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/add', {
            method: 'post',
            body: {
                what: this.refs.what.value, 
                when: this.refs.when.value, 
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                New task : 
                <label htmlFor="what"> Enter what</label>
                <input id="what" ref="what" name="what" type="text" required/>

                <label htmlFor="when">Enter when</label>
                <input id="when" ref="when" name="when" required/>

                <button>Send data!</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default ToDoForm;
```

but server side I cant get the req.body :

```
app.post('/add', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body);

    db.collection('task').countDocuments( (err, count) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        db.collection('task').insertOne({
            id : count + 1,
            what : req.body.what,
            when : req.body.when,
            done : false
        });
    });
    res.send('The \"' + req.body.what + '\" task has been added.');
});
```

Im pretty sure this has been answered many times but my search skills are limited I guess.
I am willing to change my way of doing if this is not the appropriate way.

Comment: can you post some more info about how you set up the server ? Have you added body-parsing middleware ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need refs, this should have the form value:

```
event.target.elements.what.value
event.target.elements.when.value
```

First thing the [refs doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) says is not to use them unless it's the only possible way.

Comment: no can do, I still get only `{}` in the node `console.log(req.body)` :(

Comment: First things first, isolate the problem. Do you have the problem server side or client side? Check on the devtools Network tab what exactly are you sending to the server.

Comment: well client side I already had the values with refs, i changed it to `event.target.elements.what.value` like you said, and it's suposed to work fine, but server side body is empty, there are many things in the Network tab and im not used to it, what information do you require in this exactly ?

Comment: What you need from Network is the actual message you are sending from the client to the server. There you can check for sure that you are sending what you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you create refs (*read https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html*)

The quick fix in your code is

```js
<label htmlFor="what"> Enter what</label>
<input id="what" ref={el=>this.what=el} name="what" type="text" required/>

<label htmlFor="when">Enter when</label>
<input id="when" ref={el=>this.when=el} name="when" required/>
```

and use it as

```
body: {
    what: this.what.value, 
    when: this.when.value, 
}
```

---

The other way is to use `createRef` before-hand and pass it to the `ref` attribute.

```js
class ToDoForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.what = React.createRef();
        this.when = React.createRef();
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
       event.preventDefault();

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/add', {
            method: 'post',
            body: {
                what: this.what.value, 
                when: this.when.value, 
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                New task : 
                <label htmlFor="what"> Enter what</label>
                <input id="what" ref={this.what} name="what" type="text" required/>

                <label htmlFor="when">Enter when</label>
                <input id="when" ref={this.when} name="when" required/>

                <button>Send data!</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: still empty body in the node `console.log(req.body)` :(

Comment: @FalaiseSolaire did your remove the `.refs` part from `this.refs.what.value` ?

Comment: yeah this work just fine in client side in both your and my way, this is not the problem, the problem is i get an empty body server side.

Comment: @FalaiseSolaire my mistake. Are you using body-parsing middleware to populate `req.body`?